# Can't access a protected function from another protected function within the same PHP Class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I looked a lot and didn't find a similar question so please bear with me I am still learning OOP.

I read that in a `class`, a `protected` function can be accessed from any other function, **but** it has to be within the same `class`. So why does the following code **not** work when I make the
`register_scripts()` function as `protected`? I mean, since `setup_hooks()` function is holding the `action` that will trigger the `register_scripts()` callback, and both these functions are in the same `Assets` class, so why the error on making it `protected`?

```
 class Assets{

    protected function __construct(){
        // Load all classes
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    // define hooks for the plugin here
    protected function setup_hooks(){                  
        // Actions
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'register_scripts' ] );
    }

    public function register_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mono_script', MY_DIR_URL . '/assets/script.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, cannot access protected method MWS_PLUGIN\Inc\Assets::register_scripts()

Comment: This is why: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/380668/plugin-development-using-classes-public-private-callbacks - TL;DR: WP hooks work within the global scope and cannot access private/protected methods.

Comment: @disinfor Thank you very much . Could you please enter it as your answer so that I Choose it as selected?

Comment: To be even clearer, this is actually a limitation of PHP itself. WordPress's hooks are global functions, and as noted this means they aren't part of the class itself. You can get around this, however, by using closures. https://3v4l.org/mdiX0. In your example, `setup_hooks` is _not_ "holding the action", it is referencing the action to be called later by someone else.

Comment: PHP 8.1 also includes what's called "first class callable syntax", so you can also do: https://3v4l.org/9qLOX

Comment: Personally, I'm generally against array-based callables and I avoid them whenever possible, partly because I find them ugly, but also partly because the scope issue can bite you. I'm not saying they are bad and that you shouldn't use them, because they are a totally valid language feature, it is just my own preference.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thanks so much. I will dig into PHP Closures in future :)
I could really use your help on this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453628/passing-arguments-in-php-class-via-singleton-instance

Comment: @Mr.Coder since the answer lives on another stack-site, I generally won't add it as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @disinfor, if you don't mind, I'm going to wrap this up in an answer then, just for closure? (no pun intended)

Comment: @ChrisHaas right on! You'll have a more comprehensive answer with your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @disinfor showed, this comes down to scope, and it isn't really a WordPress issue, but a PHP one. WordPress's hook system obviously doesn't live in your class, it lives in the global namespace (although that's not part of the issue) and that's the important distinction.

To your note about `setup_hooks` "holding the action", that isn't true, it is only referencing it. Whoever actually calls that reference must have the proper scope.

You can get around this, however, by using closures. Here's a sample of a class and a couple of ways to pass, along with the failure that you noticed.

```php
class Thing {
    public function publicFunction() {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
    protected function protectedFunction() {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function __construct() {
        
        // This works as expected
        test([$this, 'publicFunction']);
        
        // This all works because it is a closure
        test(
            function() {
                $this->protectedFunction();
            }
        );
        
        // This is a shorter version of the previous
        test( fn() => $this->protectedFunction() );
        
        // This does not work
        test([$this, 'protectedFunction']);
    }
}

function test(callable $func){
    $func();
}

new Thing;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mdiX0