# Passing arguments in PHP Class via Singleton instance

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP so please bear with me.

I have defined a singleton trait to store instances of all classes and it all works fine when I call the classes with `className::get_instance()`. However, I can't figure how to pass arguments to a `class`'s constuctor function with **Singleton**?

This is my **Singleton** trait:

```
 trait Singleton{

   final public static function get_instance() {

    static $instance = [];
    $called_class = get_called_class();

    if( !isset( $instance[ $called_class ] ) ) {
        $instance[$called_class] = new $called_class();
    }

    return $instance[ $called_class ];
} }
```

And this is my **New_Post** class

```
class New_Post{
    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $date ){
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->phone = $phone;
    $this->date = $date;
    }
 }
```

Now I want to call this class from a different file so normally I use:

```
New_Post::get_instance();
```

But as you can see in the `New_Post` constructor function, I need to pass `$arg1` and `$arg2` to its instance. How to go about passing them. Thanks.

Comment: A singleton might not be the best pattern for you in this case. Generally it is meant to have a single copy of `New_Post`. Would you want to allows multiple copies with different constructors parameters, so `New_Post('a')` and `New_Post('b')`? Or if you passed different parameters on the second call, they'd be ignored and you'd get the first one? A factory might be a better pattern for you (which can be backed by a singleton still).

Comment: @ChrisHaas well, no. I am using this Singleton class to just store all the classes I am geenrating. This New_Post is just one of them. Some classes need args passed to them and others dont. So, I believe @Barmar's answer is ideal if `...$args` is equivalent to JS's spread operator and it will enable passing no args or some args in a class.

Comment: That's fine, as long as you truly use it as a singleton. An example of not using it, where unexpected things might happen, is https://3v4l.org/43NIj#v8.2.2

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you so much for the patience and guidance :D

Comment: @ChrisHaas I followed Barmar's approach but now am getting this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MWS_PLUGIN\Inc\New_CPT::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\....trait-singleton.php on line 26 and exactly 5 expected..` I called the class like so: `New_CPT::get_instance( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $date );` So some of my classes will have no arguments going in them and others will have. Is Singleton not the right way for such cases? what does the `...$args` do in Singleton? I thought it allows to start a class with/without arguments passed.

Comment: You can think of `...` in this instance as "whatever is passed in the first thing, pass it directly to the second thing". In the old days we'd use `func_get_arg` and manually figure things out. but `...` is done at the language level. If you pass zero items, zero items will be passed to the constructor then.

Comment: @ChrisHaas yeah that's what I reckoned but am facing some issues. I have replied to Barmar's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251877/discussion-between-mr-coder-and-chris-haas).

Comment: @ChrisHaas  yeah that was a typo. I did correct it already. I have no idea why the blank instance, with no arguments, is not getting instantiated? Why is it requiring the 5 arguments there? I will only be able to have the 5 arguments on the form  submission page where I will grab all the $_POST data and send it to the `New_Post` class much later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `get_instance()` to take arguments and pass them along when calling `$called_class()`.

```
<?php

trait Singleton{

    final public static function get_instance(...$args) {

        static $instance = [];
        $called_class = get_called_class();

        if( !isset( $instance[ $called_class ] ) ) {
            $instance[$called_class] = new $called_class(...$args);
        }

        return $instance[ $called_class ];
    }
}

class New_Post{
    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $date ){
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->date = $date;
    }
 }
 
 $post = New_Post::get_instance("First", "Last", "email", "123-456-7890", "today");
 
 var_dump($post);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/rHscIV)

Comment: I followed your approach but now am getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MWS_PLUGIN\Inc\New_CPT::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\....trait-singleton.php on line 26 and exactly 5 expected..` I called the class like so: `New_CPT::get_instance( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $date );` So some of my classes will have no arguments going in them and others will have. Is Singleton not the right way for such cases? what does the ...$args do in Singleton? I thought it allows to start a class with/without arguments passed.

Comment: Are you sure you added `...$args` to the `new $called_class` line?

Comment: Yes. `$instance[$called_class] = new $called_class( ...$args );` And I am calling the first instance of the New_Post class as `New_Post::get_instance();` in the parent function where all classes' instances are being initialized. I have updated my OP with the new `__construct` function on `New_Post` class.

Comment: There are total 3 classes at the moment that I am initializing:
`Assets::get_instance();
        Shortcodes::get_instance();
        New_Post::get_instance();`

But since only `New_Post` class has args in `__construct' function so that's causing an issue maybe?

Comment: Ok so what I changed is that I am not calling `New_Post::get_instance()` in the parent function like other classes, instead I am using it on the spot with the form submission:
`New_Post::get_instance( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $date );` But the error is that the class `New_Post` is not found.

Comment: As long as you are getting the class via the singleton pattern, no other way, and as long as the previous note about parameters is accounted for, the point of a singleton is that it will always return what you expect it to.

Comment: @Mr.Coder I've tested my code and it works. I added a link to a demo.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much. Then I guess I am messing something :)
Even thought I have not solved it yet but I guess you can't get everything so I have to live with it. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're missing the arguments when you write `New_Post::get_instance()`.

Comment: @Barmar I get it now. I cant start that instance until it is needed, i.e. until the form is submitted. I was pre-loading it at every refresh with other classes which is why those arguments were missing :D Thanks for the patience :)